# Como converter "double" para "string" no TextField de um panel?

Tags: java, sql

```
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
    
    Alunos aluno = new Alunos();
    daoAlunos dao = new daoAlunos(dataSource);

    aluno.setAlu_nome(TFnomeAluno.getText());
    aluno.setAlu_representante(TFrepresentanteAluno.getText());
    aluno.setAlu_email(TFemailAluno.getText());
    aluno.setAlu_fone(TFfoneAluno.getText());
    aluno.setAlu_turma(TFturmaAluno.getText());
    aluno.setAlu_saldo(TFsaldoAluno.getText());
    aluno.setAlu_descricao(TFdescricaoAluno.getText());
    
    dao.create(aluno);

    this.dispose();
```

Comment: O problema em questão é o "aluno.setAlu_saldo(TFsaldoAluno.getText());"

Answer (score -2):

Vai ficar assim:

```java
 aluno.setAlu_saldo(Double.valueOf(TFsaldoAluno.getText()));
```

Prova de conceito:

```java
String varTexto = "12.34";
double varDouble = Double.valueOf(varTexto);
System.out.println(varDouble); // 12.34
```